# Translate won't work in python

Tags: python

The last time I had this error somebody suggested to use replace instead but I tried so but it didn't work,

the error:

```
line 11, in replace
    output_string = input_string.translate(rot)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

and my code

```
l = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
rot = dict()

def generate_rotated_dictionary(n):
    rot = dict((c, chr(97 + ((ord(c)-97 + n)%26) )) for c in l)

def replace(input_string):
    for n in range(1, 26):
        generate_rotated_dictionary(n)
        output_string = input_string.translate(rot)
        print(output_string)
        rot.clear()

while True:
   input_string = raw_input("Wat wilt u de-crypten?\n")
   replace(input_string)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are not using local/global variables correct. In the `generate_rotated_dictionary` function you are declaring the local variable `rot`, which seems to be meant as a global variable. Try adding `global rot` to your `generate_rotated_dictionary` function. However, you should be able to write the code without the use of global variables, which is strongly preferable.

Comment: `rot = generate_rotated_dictionary(n)` and `def generate_rotated_dictionary(n): return dict(...)`

Comment: In Python 2 `translate` expects string with 256 chars, not dictionary. Python 3 uses dictionary. [Python 2 - translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate), [Python 3 - translate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that but im using python 3 so the translate should work then right?